# Two Odes, Two Rileys?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

Let us praise... No, no more gibberish! Here you go!

> My infix is somewhere in the Middle East,
>   My prefix annoy and make you muddy,
>   My suffix a line, peculiar at least.
>   And I, concealed, is what you see!

or

> My prefix on the road, is not an island,
>   My infix is three dots on the left.
>   My suffix is to Anglo-Saxons, an island.
>   And I, and I, when would I come back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My infix is somewhere in the Middle East,

> **[Il](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il,_Iran)** is village in Iran.

My prefix annoy and make you muddy,

> **rile** - to make angry, to stir from a state of calm.

My suffix a line, peculiar at least.

> **ley** line - a supposed alignment of ancient geographical sites.

And I, concealed, is what you see!

> Yes, this is a Riley.

My prefix on the road, is not an island,

> **RI** is the state abbreviation of Rhode Island, most of which is located on the mainland of the United States.

My infix is three dots on the left.

> **[l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille)** - in Braille is a line of three dots on the left.

My suffix is to Anglo-Saxons, an island.

> **[ey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ey)** - in Anglosaxon placenames, means island, as in Jersey & Guernsey.

And I, and I, when would I come back?

> Two Rileys for the price of one - back again!!

Comment: good job! @Tom, you've got it!